# How to achieve Javascript array index comparison?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table that is styled based on cell content. Cell contents are limited to specific data so I created an array. I can style the cell if I reference an index of the array:

```
var greencell = ["item1", "item2", etc]
var cells = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if (cells[i].innerHTML == greencell[0]) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#80ff80";
  }
}
```

However, I need to access the entire array. When I set comparison `==` greencell the styling is not applied. What am I missing? Am I even approaching this correctly? Loop through the array similar to the `cells` loop and set comparison on the loop result? My mind is mush at the moment

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the array:

```
var greencell = ["item1", "item2", etc]

var cells = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("td");
var j = 0; 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < greencell.length; j++) {
        if (cells[i].innerHTML == greencell[j]) {
            cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#80ff80";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a different color for each item, you can use an array:

```
var colors = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff"];
var cells = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("td");
var j = 0; // You shouldn't redeclare the variable each iteration
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < greencell.length; j++) {
        if (cells[i].innerHTML == greencell[j]) {
            cells[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “Redeclare the variable each iteration” doesn’t make sense. `var` is a parse-time thing and an iteration is a run-time thing.

Comment: Thanks @balint I was going that direction but didn't get the syntax correct.

Comment: @Ryan Right, sorry, I'm still thinking in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if the `innerHTML` matches any element of `greencell`:

```
if (greencell.indexOf(cells[i].innerHTML) !== -1) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#80ff80";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this is nice! I find this to be the most challenging aspect of coding, so many ways to reach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a more ES6 oriented solution you could iterate over the `HTMLCollection` as an `Array` and then decide your style base on the text of the cell.

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>wrong</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>item1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var greencell = ["item1", "item2"];
var redcell = ["red", "wrong"];

var cells = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("td");

Array.from(cells).forEach(function(cell) {
  cell.style.cssText = getStyles(cell.innerHTML)
})

function getStyles(value) {
  if (greencell.indexOf(value) > -1) {
    return 'background-color: green; color: white';
  }
  if (redcell.indexOf(value) > -1) {
    return 'background-color: red; color: white';
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbc1xh26/)